# Screen resolution that my PC doesn't support

Tags: screen, resolution, monitor, screen-resolution, screen-size

This is a silly question, but I have to make sure in any case.

The maximum screen resolution that my laptop support is 1366 x 768. 
Is there a way that I could see how my screen will look like if I have bigger resolution (for example: 1440 x 900). 
I need to check how my website will look at screens with that resolution, but I don't have a device that support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible ! Go on [quirktools.com](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) write your website's Url and then you can choose different resolutions on different devices.